# Transition for table expanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-transitions

I have a table and the last  should show additional  on click. Everything works fine, but I need a transition (after click the table should expand smoothly).

My test table:

```
  <div ng-app="app">
    <table>
      <thead ng-controller="TestController">
        <tr>
          <th>
            head
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            first
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            second
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="display">
          <td>
            third
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="display">
          <td>
            fourth
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="display">
          <td>
            fifth
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-click="display = !display" class="last-color">
          <td>
            click me
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border: solid 1px;
}

td {
  border: solid 2px;
}

.last-color td {
  background-color: green;
}

tbody {
    transition: height 2s;
}
```

My example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4w1u5or/2/)

Comment: You should clarify what do you want, because *smoothly* is a loose concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, CSS3 transitions allow you to change property values smoothly (from one value to another), over a given duration. In other words, in order to see a transition working, you should specify both values in your CSS explicitly.

More over, you cannot apply height transitions to table elements (`<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc.). However, if you can wrap the contents with `<div>` elements, you can apply CSS transitions to the `<div>` elements.

Just for example: https://jsfiddle.net/r4w1u5or/3/